# Extremely long garbage collection times

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

We have a web application running Java 6, Tomcat 6, Spring Framework 3, Hibernate 4, EhCache.
We have a problem with extremely long garbage collection times which can take 30 seconds or longer, leaving the application unresponsive.

We're currently in testing but apart from the obvious: add more memory, I was wondering if there are aspects we could tune to reduce garbage collection time.

The major contributor to memory use is EHCache as we are aggressively caching. But I always find it hard to size the EHCache stores (the new EhCache byte size stores, lead to all sorts of problems with us because the cached object graphs can be quite large).

These are my settings for the JVM

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -server -Xms256m -Xmx704m XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=/usr/share/scripts/on_server_crash.sh -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/var/log/tomcat6 -XX:MaxPermSize=192m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
```

Comment: Do you get these long times before memory reach the max of 704MB? The JVM can be a bit "aggressive" in trying to reduce used memory (and possibly relocate it) before deciding to increase the memory used. Does it behave the same way if you use -Xms704m -Xmx704m starting up?

Comment: Using "jstat -gc 1s pid"  you can see if your memory usage hits the nurseries or if the memory allocation between nurseries, eden and old should be changed.

Comment: Short of profiling you application with JProdilfer/Yourkit, you wont have any solid suggestions.

Comment: Of course, the ideal solution is concurrent GC.  But there are only a few implementations of that.

Comment: @Roger setting -Xms704m -Xmx704m did seem to help a little, but it's hard to say. Still taking more than 25 seconds. I have my EHCache setup set to diskoverflow="true". I'm wondering if the problem could be related to large amounts of disk reads/writes. The memory on the box seems more or less ok:

Comment: Memory:
                 total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
    Mem:           998        952         46          0          6         95
    -/+ buffers/cache:        850        148
    Swap:         2047         28       2019
    Total:        3045        980       2065

Comment: Do you have a lot of small, same typed objects?  What about building your own cache using a static array or something, and manage that yourself.  Some work, but if you can move lots of small stuff out of a cache that would require garbage collection, maybe you could reduce the work needed when gc kicks in.

Answer (score 4):

To reduce GC times, the best thing you can do is use off heap memory. If you can move as much of your large data as possible you can reduce your full GC time to as low as 10 milli-second even with 100s of MB of off heap memory. I believe Ehcache support off heap data stores, but if it doesn't or you can't use it I suggest you look at alternatives which do.

Given you only have a 700 MB maximum memory size it appears you are running on a server with very limited memory. Otherwise I would suggest you start with a maximum of 8 or 16 GB and reduce the memory size if you believe you don't really need it.

Comment: Memory size shouldn't be an issue in GC times. Only number of objects that are created before GC begins.

Comment: @user2763361 The number of objects is very important and other factors like hte number of references and which generation those references go, but it is the size you can see in monitoring tools. If you reduce the memory consumed you can improve performance because this usually means reducing the number of objects and the amount of reference indirection. In short, you are right, but memory usage is easier to measure.

Comment: Well said. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21675709/how-to-find-which-objects-are-creating-the-most-garbage

Answer (score 1):

There is an excellent tool from FourSquare folks. Check this link and quick example they have. [Foursquare Heap tool.](https://github.com/foursquare/heapaudit) . Based on diagnostics that you find in any of the above mentioned tools, most sorted solution to resolve the issue will be to either to add more RAM or add power to your CPU processor. If you are open to some infrastructure changes check  [Zing from Azul Systems](http://www.azulsystems.com/technology/java-heap-size). But I think the second option might be a stretch.