# How to find which objects are creating the most garbage

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I have an application with about 80 instances of 80 different classes. The amount of garbage generated by some subset of these classes is unacceptable and stop the world pauses are too long, since my application is real time.

What I want to find is which classes are responsible for creating the largest *number* of objects on heap (not aggregate size, but raw number of objects), since this is what causes stop the world pauses to take so long.

How do I find this out?

If JVisualVM is required, I have this.

Comment: `If JVisualVM is required, I have this.` So what stopping you to use that ?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Nothing is stopping me from using JVisualVM, just like nothing is stopping me from using any other tool. The issue is I don't know how to answer the specific question of number of objects generated by the worst of the worst classes (in this tool or any other that I've used in my past).

Comment: Which GC are you using? Which Java distribution and version? How long are the stop the world pauses? What would be an acceptable duration for your use case? How did you measure the stop the world duration? If you have only 80 instances, and this number does not change, then by definition no new instances are being created, and therefore no garbage is being created... can you clarify what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very lightweight approach to look at the number of objects per class is **Class Histogram**.

Just generate class histogram by `jmap -histo <PID>`.

Use `-XX:+PrintClassHistogramBeforeFullGC`, `-XX:+PrintClassHistogramAfterFullGC` to see class histograms when your stop-the-world pause occurs. You can compare the snapshot before/after to see which class instances get collected during the stop-the-world pause.

See more details in [Profiling number of garbage-collected object instances per class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8126868/772000).

Answer (score 2):

Try JProfiler, there's at least a free trial. One of the memory views tells you which classes have the most instances created (and how many). You can also use memory recording; start recording, set a "mark", run an operation you think creates garbage, stop recording, see which classes have the most instances created since the "mark" was set. Basically, you need a good profiler, doesn't matter much which one. Typically the commercial ones are better, in my experience.

UPDATE: a good profiler will tell you exactly how many instances of a class exist.  This sounds like what you are asking for.

Comment: You need a good profiler... and the will to go read its documentation and experiment with it for extended periods of time to see what you can do with it.